# How to remove System Tools virus?

Tags: windows-xp, virus, malware

My Windows XP netbook is infected with System Tools Virus? Does anyone know how to remove this virus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that with any serious system infection, you **can not guarantee** that the malware can be fully removed. That being said, you might be better off just backing up your important data and performing a complete system reinstall.

Anyway, if you haven't done so already, install an up to date anti virus software like [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/), [AVG](http://free.avg.com/de-en/homepage), [Avast](http://www.avast.com/), etc. Do a complete system scan and see what you can remove.

You could also try to manually remove the malware. Below is something from a [Symantec forum](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/system-tool-malware-or-spyware). But be aware of the possibility that this will probably not work perfectly on a running infected system.

```
Stop These System Tool 2011 Processes:
5648541024.exe
System Tool 2011.exe

Find and Delete These System Tool 2011 Files:
%AppData%\[random]\
%AppData%\5648541024
%AppData%\5648541024\5648541024.bat
%AppData%\5648541024\5648541024.cfg
%AppData%\5648541024\5648541024.exe
%UserProfile%\Desktop\System Tool 2011.lnk
%UserProfile%\Start Menu\Programs\System Tool 2011.lnk

Remove These System Tool 2011 Registry Values:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\System Tool 2011
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run “5648541024?
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run “[random]”
```

Comment: good advice, HIGHLY recommend MSE! (Microsoft security essentials)

Answer (score 0):

I successfully removed this using [BitDefender Rescue CD](http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/)
A users guide can be found [here](http://www.techmixer.com/bitdefender-rescue-cd-with-auto-update-virus-definition-features/), make sure you are connected to the internet to download the newest definitions.